# What are the legal implications of a Muslim woman marrying outside her faith?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, non-muslim

From a SeekersHub post *[Advice to a Christian Man Who Wants to Marry a Muslim Woman](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2012/07/22/advice-to-a-christian-man-who-wants-to-marry-a-muslim-woman/)* by Ustadha Zaynab Ansari, we have the following:

> Given that you’ve clearly thought this situation through, I would now offer that the onus is on the woman whom you wish to marry. After all, your religious beliefs may not prevent you from marrying outside of your faith but hers do and **it is her responsibility to consider the implications — whether spiritual, social, or legal (were she to travel to a Muslim-majority country) — of marrying outside of her faith**.

I'm particularly interested in the legal implications:

**Question**: What are the legal implications of a Muslim woman marrying outside her faith?

The fatwa does not go into detail.  I'm not clear on what the fatwa is talking about, since presumably non-Muslim marriages are recognized as marriages in Muslim-majority countries.  Nor am I aware of any sharia punishment for such a marriage.

Comment: Welcome back Reb!

Comment: A marriage between a Muslim woman and a Non-Muslim man is not recognized in Islam, so any contact with him would be considered as if he was a stranger to her. Intercourse would be punishable as zina, for example.

Comment: @G.Bach do you have any evidences for the punishment? Fact is the marriage would be annulled in dar al-Islam and it has a status of zina as it is illegal based on 2:221 (http://legacy.quran.com/2/221).

Comment: @Medi1Saif I don't understand the question. The marriage would be Islamically invalid, thus sex would be zina, for which there is hadd. I thought this would be covered extensively on islam.se already, I don't see what would be contentious here?

Comment: [60:10](https://quran.com/60/10) is relevant. The marriage would be void and the two would be separated. They also won't inherit from each other etc.

Comment: I presume that you are referring to the legal implications in a hypothetical country that is ruled by Islamic law, and you are only referring to the legal implications affecting the wife (not the husband, or their offspring)? Even then, this may prove to be too broad.